# Creating multiple directories from vars in ansible vars file

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I am looking to create a multitude of directories on my given server by passing in vars from an ansible .yml vars file. I am currently trying to use Jinja templating to pass the directory names in.
The vars file looks like this;

```
BTG-VELOCITY:
    type: PBSTP
    accept: 1010
GFAM:
    type: PBSTP
    connect: 1010
ONEZERO2:
    type: TRADESTREAM
GUANFABANK:
    type: FXSIM
MAINBANK:
    type: FXSIM
TYPOBANK:
    type: TRADESTREAM
TEST-BANK:
    type: PBSTP
    connect: 32620
    accept: 33620
```

And I wish to create a directory for each customer name listed. So ideally I will end up with a directory in a given folder for each 'TYPOBANK','MAINBANK' etc.
The way I am trying to this at the minute is as follows in my playbook;

```
- include_vars:
    file: /home/vagrant/stunnelSimAnsPractice/roles/ns16/vars/customers.yml
    name: customers
- file:
    path: /home/vagrant/stunnelSimAnsPractice/roles/ns16/sessions/{%for cust, config in customers.items() %}{{cust}}{% endfor %}
    state: directory
```

But this outputs one directory with all the customer names combinded, as shown below. Any suggestions on how to create individual directories for each customer? Thank you

```
├── sessions
│   └── GFAMTEST-BANKBTG-VELOCITYTYPOBANKMAINBANKGUANFABANKONEZERO2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't loop inside a single parameter in Ansible.

Use [loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html) as Ansible was designed to:

```
- file:
    path: /home/vagrant/stunnelSimAnsPractice/roles/ns16/sessions/{{ item }}
    state: directory
  with_items:     ### and here you need to put the list containing the directory names
```

<sup>Unfortunately you did not provide the full definition of variables, so you need to customise the code to suite your needs.</sup>